# How to return string instead of Observable with @angular/http

Tags: angular, observable

I am hooking Angular 4 with .net core WEB API.

The Web API is returning a CustomerName in string based on the Id passed in.

This is the service method in Angular 4.
I understand that angular/http must return an Observable because it is an Async call.

But how do I return a string instead?
or how do I access the data within the Observable object from the calling method?

```
    getCustomerName(id: number): Observable<any>{
return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/getCustomerName/' + id )
    .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json() )
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To access data from observable, in your service return the response you get from the api like this:

```
getCustomerName(id: number): Observable<any>{
     return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/getCustomerName/' + id );
   }
```

and in your component call the method of the service as:

```
getCustomerName(id).subscribe(
   data => {
   console.log(JSON.parse(data));
},
error => {
   console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I get this error.    NodeInvocationException: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0

Comment: console data only instead of parsing it in JSON and check what are you getting in the response

Comment: If we are not returning any JSON object then angular throws an Unexpected token (any alphabet) in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () exception.

Comment: console.log(data) works...i get my expected value. however, the subscribe bit is not working...it is an async call, so assigning to a local variable is not executing that code.          var retval: "";
                    this.service.getCustomerName(value).subscribe(
                        data => {
                            console.log(data); // this works

                            retval = data;
                        },
                        error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        }); return retval; //undefined here

Comment: You can use a global variable for that

Comment: it’s not running the subscribe

Comment: if you don't want async calls then use maps in service

Answer (score 0):

use this function with a map operator:

```
private extractData(res) {
    let body = res.json();  // If response is a JSON use json()
    if (body) {
        return body.data || body;
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

and in the service use map like this:

```
return this.http.post(url, body, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
```

If its not a json then simply omit the parsing line

Comment: for got to mention, in the component there is a function that calls another function in the service. So its like component function getData would call service.getdata.subscribe(data=>console.log(data))

Comment: Does it even work? I get error message that *Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>...