# Eliminating subscribe(...) by returning string instead of Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I've been requested to investigate how to make a call to a service but return the final result instead of an observable. In the service, there's a method like this.

```
getToken(name: string, pass: string): string {
  const url = "https://localhost:44310/api/Security/login";
  const data = { name, pass };

  return this.http.post<any>(url, data);
}
```

In the component that will use it, we subscribe to it and consume whatever pops out from the result (or act on the error). Now, I'd like to introduce a private field that will be read when invoking *getToken(...)* and returned **if it's been assigned**. Otherwise, I'd like to do a POST and store the result, then return it.

```
private token: string;

getToken(name: string, pass: string): string {
  if(this.token)
    return this.token;

  const url = "https://localhost:44310/api/Security/login";
  const data = { name, pass };

  this.http.post<any>(url, data)
    .subscribe(
      suc => this.token = suc,
      err => this.token = null);

  return this.token;
}
```

Now, this will obviously fail, because the asynchronously assigned value to *this.token* isn't there yet at the point of leaving the method. I doubt that putting it into the success callback like this

```
this.http.post<any>(url, data)
  .subscribe(
    suc => { this.token = suc; return this.token; }
    err => this.token = null);
```

will do any different. At the moment I'm stuck and start to suspect that there's no way to return a fix, realized value eliminating the subscription in the component.

Is there a way to introduce a field as described above?

I've tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47432099/1525840) but it produced error: *Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'*.

Comment: You need to use `map(...)` within the `pipe(...)` operator. Does that fix your issue?

Comment: `I'd like to do a POST and store the result, then return it.`  You can't do this with an Async operation.  That's why observables exist.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm perfectly clear that it needs to be async operation. My question is if it's possible to encapsulate it somehow and return a simple string (if assigned since before) or (otherwise, if the string hasn't been stored yet) return the async value after a while keeping the executing method in the component locked.

Comment: @KonradViltersten yes you could theoretically do that, but it would be an absolute programming nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You shouldn't want to remove the observable from the call stack**.  You haven't provided any reason to do so.  Observables are by far more useful in an async call stack which you have.

It sounds like your *actual problem* is *caching the result so the code doesn't make duplicate calls*.  That's is very easy to do.

```js
private token: BehaviorSubject<string|null> = new BehaviorSubject<string|null>(null);
private token$ = this.token
  .asObservable()
  .pipe(filter((value) => value != null));

getToken(name: string, pass: string): observable<string> {

  const url = "https://localhost:44310/api/Security/login";
  const data = { name, pass };

  if (this.token.value == null) {
    this.http.post<any>(url, data)
      .subscribe(
        value => this.token.next(value),
        _ => this.token.next(null));
  }

  return this.token$;
}
```

Subscriber example:

```js
  someObject.getToken(params)
    .subscribe(token => {
      // when token is available it will not be null.
      // since the source is a BehaviorSubject, we get the last value
    });
```

**note:** make sure you unsubscribe if you aren't doing UI Pipe Async.

Subject Reference:

[image: Subject Types]

> My question is if it's possible to encapsulate it somehow and return a simple string (if assigned since before) or (otherwise, if the string hasn't been stored yet) return the async value after a while keeping the executing method in the component locked.

Yes you theoretically could, but this is an absolutely terrible idea:

```js
private token: string | null = null;
getToken(name: string, pass: string): string | observable<string>{

  if (this.token != null) {
    return token;
  }

  const url = "https://localhost:44310/api/Security/login";
  const data = { name, pass };

  return this.http.post<any>(url, data)
      .tap(value => this.token = value);
}
```

Now you've provided either a `string` or `observable<string>` which does exactly what you asked, however your consumers now have to jump through a ton of hoops to actually do what they need to do, and anyone who reads this is literally going to think WTF.

subscriber:

```js
   var result = someobject.getToken(params);
   if (result typeof 'string') {
     dosomethingwithstring(result);
   }
   else {
     result.subscribe(result2 => dosomethingwithstring(result));
   }
```

That's just a terrible pattern to leave other programmers with and even try to maintain.

Comment: What is the type of `token$`? It's `Observable<string>` or `Observable<string|null>`? I'm a bit unclear why the type of the `BehaviorSubject` can't be string only since a string can assume the value of null. Isn't it simpler to have `Observable<string>` only? Complexity decreases then...

Comment: I also wonder (coming from C# direction), if it wouldn't be cleaner to declare the properties as you did but assign the stuff to them in the constructor. So we'd have *private token: BehaviorSubject<string>* and in constructor `this.token=new BehaviorSubject<string>`.

Comment: No you cannot assign [null to a string](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhtATgSzAcxgXhmAVwBsiBuIA).  Typescript is not C#.  The type of `token$` is technically `Observable<string|null>` but because the pipe filters null from being emitted (which I believe typescript can imply) it's actually `Observable<string>`

Comment: Cleaner?  That's a matter of opinion.  [Technically they're literally the same compiled](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FkCeBhVDARjgG8AoOKuMKASwDcUZg4UAuOAOwFcBbAEbAoAbkrUEELmhhQeCGNAAUASjLjq1GAAs6aAHQo4AXjhExmgL4a4AMwgRV6zZsnSISYPqQQA5kp09QxULamtrclBIWERCTFwCdDQAJmdqWkZmVg5ufiEoEzMbNxk5BWU1Cisbe0dKm1cpNA8vH39AgxQQm3CgA).

Comment: As for C#, it has [allowed expression-bodied function members since version 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#expression-bodied-function-members) which it basically the same thing.

Comment: And [Auto-property initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#auto-property-initializers)...